# Pass a command into mysql login

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm setting up aliases for a new development environment and I would really like to be able to pass the `pager less -S` command to my mysql login.

I looked at the manual, all I could really see was the `-e` flag, however that quits once it's done, so that did not work.

Ideally it would be like this:

```sh
mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname -e "pager less -S"
```

However, as explained that doesn't work, any alternatives that you guys know of? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your own my.cnf file on a per-user basis. Create the file:

```
vi ~/.my.cnf
```

And add this to it:

```
[client]
pager = "less -S"
```